# Websphere Commerce V7 registry refresh failure

Tags: registry, refresh, wcs

For the past few days, we have been noticing a registry refresh failure happening every day on some of our production servers.There are some 3-4 different kind of exceptions thrown every day.
giving some examples :

```
[11/19/14 5:58:14:264 GMT] 00000135 RemoteExcepti E   CNTR0019E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "findAll". Exception data: com.ibm.websphere.csi.CSITransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: 
    javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.completeTxTimeout(TransactionControlImpl.java:1376)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.preInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:274)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.UOWControlImpl.preInvoke(UOWControlImpl.java:254)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:3897)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3269)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objects.EJSRemoteCMPLanguageHome_c0ee4bdc.findAll(EJSRemoteCMPLanguageHome_c0ee4bdc.java:63)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objects._LanguageHome_Stub.findAll(_LanguageHome_Stub.java:68)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objects.LanguageAccessBean.findAll(LanguageAccessBean.java:67)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objsrc.LanguageCache$MyFindAll.generateCacheableData(LanguageCache.java:209)
    at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.AbstractFinderResult.invokeFinder(AbstractFinderResult.java:602)
    at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheableFinderResult.invokeFinder(CacheableFinderResult.java:195)
    at com.ibm.commerce.datatype.AbstractEntityAccessBeanFinderResult.invokeFinder(AbstractEntityAccessBeanFinderResult.java:278)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.TransactionCacheableCommandHelper.executeFromTransactionCache(TransactionCacheableCommandHelper.java:143)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractFinderResultCache.myInvokeFinder(AbstractFinderResultCache.java:1237)
    at com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractFinderResultCache.invokeFinder(AbstractFinderResultCache.java:1102)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objsrc.LanguageCache.invokeFinder(LanguageCache.java:586)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objsrc.LanguageCache.myFindAllCollection(LanguageCache.java:299)
    at com.ibm.commerce.common.objsrc.LanguageCache.findAll(LanguageCache.java:264)
    at com.ibm.commerce.registry.LanguageRegistry.retrieve(LanguageRegistry.java:204)
    at com.ibm.commerce.registry.LanguageRegistry.refresh(LanguageRegistry.java:177)
    at com.ibm.commerce.registry.RegistryManager.refreshAll(RegistryManager.java:219)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.commands.RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.refreshRegistry(RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.java:182)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.commands.RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.performExecute(RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.java:136)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.ECCommandTarget.executeCommand(ECCommandTarget.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.command.CommandCache.executeCommand(CommandCache.java:332)
    at com.ibm.websphere.command.CacheableCommandImpl.execute(CacheableCommandImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.commerce.command.AbstractECTargetableCommand.execute(AbstractECTargetableCommand.java:234)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.BaseComponentImpl.executeCommand(BaseComponentImpl.java:202)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.WebAdapterComponentImpl.executeCommand(WebAdapterComponentImpl.java:46)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objimpl.WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.executeCommand(WebAdapterServiceBeanBase.java:58)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objects.EJSLocalStatelessWebAdapterService_ce749a4a.executeCommand(EJSLocalStatelessWebAdapterService_ce749a4a.java:31)
    at com.ibm.commerce.component.objects.WebAdapterServiceAccessBean.executeCommand(WebAdapterServiceAccessBean.java:160)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.SchedulerJob.process(SchedulerJob.java:520)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.SchedulerSecurityPriviledgedAction.run(SchedulerSecurityPriviledgedAction.java:59)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.SchedulerJob.run(SchedulerJob.java:1068)
    at com.ibm.commerce.threadmanagement.internal.BaseWork.run(BaseWork.java:139)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:264)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:228)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
Caused by: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.completeTxTimeout(TranManagerImpl.java:527)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.completeTxTimeout(TranManagerSet.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.completeTxTimeout(TransactionControlImpl.java:1368)
    ... 41 more

Another example :
[11/12/14 5:55:06:024 GMT]     FFDC Exception:com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerManagedBeanO.store ProbeId:472 Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerManagedBeanO@12ab12ab
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.11.77
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:668)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.b(jn.java:2230)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.c(jn.java:2213)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.k(cb.java:369)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.a(cb.java:61)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.a(q.java:50)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.b(sb.java:226)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.oc(kn.java:2930)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.b(kn.java:3876)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.b(kn.java:4047)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.gc(kn.java:743)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.executeUpdate(kn.java:722)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1152)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:793)
    at com.ibm.commerce.base.objects.EJSJDBCPersisterCMPSchedulerBroadcastBean_ccbb593d.store(EJSJDBCPersisterCMPSchedulerBroadcastBean_ccbb593d.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerManagedBeanO.store(ContainerManagedBeanO.java:735)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EntityBeanO.beforeCompletion(EntityBeanO.java:1237)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerTx.beforeCompletion(ContainerTx.java:721)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.tran.SyncDriver.beforeCompletion(SyncDriver.java:280)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.coreDistributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredSyncs.distributeBefore(RegisteredSyncs.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.prePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:2323)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:541)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:986)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:920)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.commerce.server.TransactionManager.commit(TransactionManager.java:183)
    at com.ibm.commerce.server.TransactionManager.commit(TransactionManager.java:241)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.commands.RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.updateState(RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.java:352)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.commands.RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.refreshRegistry(RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.java:198)
    at com.ibm.commerce.scheduler.commands.RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.performExecute(RefreshLocalRegistryCmdImpl.java:136)

one more:

11/13/14 5:55:01:603 GMT] 00000008 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W: Transaction 00000149A7B3897F00000001001F589FFF2F876A1300AAE3A7ED20831067E29B8BFE6E2500000149A7B3897F00000001001F589FFF2F876A1300AAE3A7ED20831067E29B8BFE6E2500000001 has timed out after 300 seconds.
[11/13/14 5:55:01:605 GMT] 00000008 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[WorkManager.broadcast : 83,5,reserved: WC_arglp]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.b(z.java:199)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:259)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:372)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.v(z.java:1147)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.cb.c(cb.java:53)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.q.c(q.java:44)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.rb.j(rb.java:147)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.jn.kb(jn.java:2047)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.b(kn.java:3900)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.fc(kn.java:702)
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.executeQuery(kn.java:672)
    com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1082)
    com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:703)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.EJSJDBCPersisterCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionBean_6f241499.load(EJSJDBCPersisterCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionBean_6f241499.java:166)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerManagedBeanO.load(ContainerManagedBeanO.java:1035)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.ContainerManagedBeanO.loadForEnlist(ContainerManagedBeanO.java:992)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.EntityBeanO.enlist(EntityBeanO.java:785)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.OptCEntityActivationStrategy.atActivate(OptCEntityActivationStrategy.java:168)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.activateBean(Activator.java:599)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.activateBean_Common(EJSHome.java:2052)
    com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.activateBean(EJSHome.java:1890)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.EJSJDBCPersisterCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionBean_6f241499.findByPrimaryKey(EJSJDBCPersisterCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionBean_6f241499.java:423)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.EJSCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionHomeBean_6f241499.findByPrimaryKey(EJSCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionHomeBean_6f241499.java:31)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.EJSRemoteCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionHome_6f241499.findByPrimaryKey(EJSRemoteCMPCatalogGroupDescriptionHome_6f241499.java:112)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects._CatalogGroupDescriptionHome_Stub.findByPrimaryKey(_CatalogGroupDescriptionHome_Stub.java:236)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.CatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.instantiateEJBByPrimaryKey(CatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.java:239)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.beansrc.CompactCatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.instantiateEJBByPrimaryKey(CompactCatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.java:241)
    com.ibm.ivj.ejb.runtime.AbstractEntityAccessBean._instantiate(AbstractEntityAccessBean.java:173)
    com.ibm.ivj.ejb.runtime.AbstractEntityAccessBean.refreshCopyHelper(AbstractEntityAccessBean.java:309)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.CatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.refreshCopyHelper(CatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.java:271)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objsrc.CachedCatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.refreshCopyHelper(CachedCatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBean.java:243)
    com.ibm.commerce.datatype.AbstractEntityAccessBeanFinderResult.invokeFinder(AbstractEntityAccessBeanFinderResult.java:317)
    com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractFinderResultCache.myInvokeFinder(AbstractFinderResultCache.java:1411)
    com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractFinderResultCache.invokeFinder(AbstractFinderResultCache.java:1102)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objsrc.CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.invokeFinder(CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.java:639)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objsrc.CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.invokeSingleCatalogGroupDescriptionAccessBeanFinder(CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.java:610)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objsrc.CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.findByPrimaryKey(CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.java:229)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objsrc.CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.findByPrimaryKey(CatalogGroupDescriptionCache.java:182)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objimpl.CatalogGroupBeanBase.getDescription(CatalogGroupBeanBase.java:578)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objimpl.CatalogGroupBeanBase.getFallbackDescription(CatalogGroupBeanBase.java:641)
    com.ibm.commerce.base.objects.ECEntityBean.getFallbackDescription(ECEntityBean.java:276)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objimpl.CatalogGroupBeanBase.getDescription(CatalogGroupBeanBase.java:603)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.EJSRemoteCMPCatalogGroup_8e5bb4d3.getDescription(EJSRemoteCMPCatalogGroup_8e5bb4d3.java:1043)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects._CatalogGroup_Stub.getDescription(_CatalogGroup_Stub.java:872)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objects.CatalogGroupAccessBean.getDescription(CatalogGroupAccessBean.java:890)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.objsrc.CachedCatalogGroupAccessBean.getDescription(CachedCatalogGroupAccessBean.java:298)
    com.ibm.commerce.catalog.helper.SearchNavigationCache$MyFindCategoryNameAndParent.generateCacheableData(SearchNavigationCache.java:125)
    com.ibm.commerce.datatype.AbstractFinderResult.invokeFinder(AbstractFinderResult.java:602)
    com.ibm.commerce.datatype.CacheableFinderResult.invokeFinder(CacheableFinderResult.java:195)
    com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractFinderResultCache.myInvokeFinder(AbstractFinderResultCache.java:1411)
    com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractFinderResultCache.invokeFinder(AbstractFinderResultCache.java:1102)
    com.ibm.commerce.dynacache.commands.AbstractDistributedMapCache$Cache.getOrPut(AbstractDistributedMapCache.java
```

We have been getting these exceptions repeatedly.

Can anyone suggest why is this happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: Seems an apar handles this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Saw today that IBM has created an APAR for an registry update issue.

https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/blogs/wcs/entry/ensure_you_have_jr48163?lang=en

------------- old below --------------

We usually don't refresh registries by scheduling because configuration changes could be replicated in an unpredictable way. But if you run this scheduled command it's required to be done with an application type of BROADCAST.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/concepts/cjsjobs.htm